# Setting text for UITextView causes reset to default font and color issue

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I am using auto layout for a month and this is a pain in my head. By some reasons if I set text to my textview that has constraints, App shows me not the same color and font as I set in storyboard, but seems default.

I am not sure if this simulator issue maybe?

I set text programmatically in `-viewDidLoad`

If I not set text in viewDidLoad:

[image]

If I set text in viewDidLoad:

[image]

Comment: Add screen shots if possible.

Comment: @Kampai, as you can see if I don't set text in code. The textview has white text, but if I set my textView.text = @"some text"; it cause font issue and color. Like seems use default settings.

Comment: Is it possible that you set attributed text string in storyboard.

Comment: @gabbler, no the text is plain. and there are no any code that change text color or font.

Comment: @gabbler alos I have two setups in storyboard for all iphones and for all ipads. So for iPad I have set for textview alignment center for text, but seems it inherit some properties from iphone, because for iPhone I use justify text and the same I can see for iPad right now.

Comment: Did you use size class? which size class you use for all ipads?

Comment: @gabbler wRegular hRegular

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using?, I think you might be setting a new textview instead of setting the text of the existing one

Comment: @Fantini I have not got any code, just viewDidLoad where I set one IBOutlet property theTextView. theTextView is the same object for all sizes I use. In any case were is the default white text. If I set another object then I think we need to see white text that I set in storyboard and as you assumed we then need to see white and black overlapped text.

Comment: @Fantini, I have answered my question. But I don't know why it affects on font and color

Comment: @gabbler I have answered my question. But I don't know why it affects on font and color

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the selectedRange has changed something.

Answer (score 7):

I found the issue if I uncheck Selectable checkbox in storyboard for UITextView then it causes this issue if I set text form the code. When I mark it checked again then it resolves my issue.

[image]